# How to select specific key after filtering the data using YQ

Tags: jq, yq

myres.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "id_1",
    "name": "default",
  },
  {
    "id": "id_2",
    "name": "name2",
  },
  {
    "id": "id_3",
    "name": "name3",
  }
]
```

I waanted to get only `name` whose `id = 3`
I am able to filter out the object using yq following command

```
 yq -r '.[] | select(.id == "id_3" )' myres.json
```

and output is

```
{
    "id": "id_3",
    "name": "name3",  
}
```

I tried with `with_entries`,  `from_entries` but no luck.
Thanks in advance !!
I am using `kislyuk/yq 2.14.1` version

Comment: `yq -r '.[] | select(.id == "id_3" ).name` is all you need

Comment: `jq '.[] | select(.id=="id_3") | "\(.id) \(.name)"' Input_file` In `jq` you could try something like this. written and teste with shown samples. Though I had to fix posted json in question but this worked with fixed json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per @Inian, I made few changes in query as follows according to my requirements.

```
yq -r '.[] | select(.id=="id_2").name' s.txt
```